# Image loading time

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click on my website sometimes you can visually see the images slowly loading into the place. I don't really like this and if possible would like to prevent it from happening.

From reading round it seems preloading images is the solution I'm looking for? Let me know if that's correct or if there is a better way.

On this forum I see lots of answers to preloading images and below is a code I think works but I want to change it slightly:

```
var preloadImages = [ img/1.jpg,img/2.jpg];

for(var i = 0 ; i < preloadImages.length; i++) {
   new Image().src = preloadImages[i];
}
```

I think this code above works but it requires me to type in every image source into an array. On my website there are lots of images and I will probably continue to add more. So is there a way to push all the image sources into the array without actually typing them in. So as I add more images the preloading take care of itself.

Comment: Checkout this github project https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to go down the route you already have you could search the entire DOM for  tags first and then add them to the array.

Perhaps something along these lines:

```
images = []
$(body).find('img').each ->
  imgSrc = $(this).attr('src')
  image.push imgSrc
i = 0
while i < preloadImages.length
  (new Image).src = preloadImages[i]
  i++
```

That will need jQuery and probably some tweaking. I can't imagine this being the best approach however as you still need to wait for the DOM, then jQuery to load and then run through the entire DOM with the function(s).

If the issue is more that the content is moving around you can (and probably should) prevent this by giving the  tag itself a height and width if you know it in advance.

Additionally it's always worth optimizing your images (either by hand or on build/compile using something like Gulp.js) if you haven't already. It's incredible how much you can reduce load times by simply by using the optimal image (in terms of size and format).

Answer (score 0):

You can call below function after page load

```
function preloadImages(){
    $('img').each(function(){
        new Image().src = this.src;
    });
}
```

You can use this function to set multiple after-page-load functions

```
function addLoadEvent(func) {
    var oldonload = window.onload;
    if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
        window.onload = function(){
            func();
        };
    } else {
        window.onload = function() {
            if (oldonload) {
                oldonload();
            }
            func();
        };
    }
}
```

then add your function like this

```
addLoadEvent(preloadImages);
```

But I don't think you can *really* pre-load images like this. To really pre-load images, you have to start loading those images as soon as your DOM starts to render on the client-side. And that means loading them in the head section. But if you do that, because you don't have your html just yet, you will *not* be able to run the above function, because it needs the DOM to be fully downloaded. You have to hardcode your image sources into javascript like you already did, and put your function as the first thing in the head section.